# Laravel check max length of input field?

Tags: php, laravel

how to check if input length is more than three in blade file?

```
if(!$errors->has('user') && strlen('user') > 3)
```

this thing not work

Comment: `strlen('user') > 3` checks if the _literal_ text value `user` has more than three bytes.

Comment: but how to check input length is more than 3?

Comment: By getting the actual _value_ of that parameter, and then using strlen on that?

Comment: strlen(request()->input('user')) > 3

this thing not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you do not want the length of the input itself, but the maximum length of the input. strlen(request()->input('user')) will give you the length of the input itself, it will not give you the max length of the input. this issue can not be resolved by php itself as far as I am concerned. The only way you can get the value in the controller is by using js to keep the max length attribute in a hidden input and then using that hidden input in the controller.Such as:

```
{!! Form::hidden('max','',array('class'=>'','id'=>'max')) !!}
```

js:

```
var el = document.getElementById("user");
$("#max").val(el);
```

Then in controller:

```
strlen(request()->input('max'))
```